# setInterval callback function is not dynamic (Redux props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setinterval

I have a simple js `setInterval`, where my callback is simply checking some `Redux` variable:

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(props.myStateVariable);
}, 5000);
```

The problem is that it just prints whatever the variable was at the time of this `setInterval`'s instantiation. How to make it dynamic? Thanks

**edit**

And what if this `myStateVariable` is a string variable of a long, editable text, so I'd rather not re-set this timeout every time someone types a letter?

Comment: Have you tried to pass it as a function parameter?

Comment: Have you tried using useSelector hook? That's what I use to get dynamic values from redux store. https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: Actually no, none of the comments work...

Comment: @true_gler You mean pass the props value? But that's the thing: I don't know this value initially and want to infer it every 5s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store the interval function in a variable, override the interval function every time props.myStateVariable changes:

```
const interval = useRef(null);
useEffect(()=> {
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(props.myStateVariable);
  }, 5000);
  return ()=> clearInterval(interval.current);
}, [props.myStateVariable]);
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to override the interval every time the property changes, you can use the `useRef` hook to store the property value. This way you can access it's value:

```
const propRef = useRef(null);
propRef.current = props.myStateVariable;

useEffect(()=> {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(propRef.current);
  }, 5000);
  return ()=> clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, man, I was fighting with it for too long :)

Comment: Your welcome. Also you don't need to create a ref, you can create a variable inside useEffect and it should work too. useEffect(()=> {
 const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(props.myStateVariable);
  }, 5000);
  return ()=> clearInterval(interval);
}, [props.myStateVariable]). The ref is useful if you need to use it in other places

Comment: I know that, of course, thanks again. Now I feel stupid :)

Comment: I've edited my question,maybe you have an answer?

Comment: Yes, see my edit, the solution is very similar :).

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow. If it works, it's just brilliant, and I appreciate your help very much!!

Comment: OK, But I don't see any problem to override the interval function because every time this property changes the component will re-render, and the interval could be updated.

Comment: I get an error: "Cannot assign to 'current' because it's a read-only property"

Comment: Ok, it works now :) I couldn't do what you suggested, as I just check this value, in some totally other component. The interval has to be fixed. Thanks a bunch again, it was a brilliant idea!

Comment: Like tried with state, didn't work. Tried with immutable js, didn't work. Tried with redux didn't work. Seriously react functional components has some issues about rendering..

Your solution worked bro.. Thank you